# Unpivot with multiple where clauses

Tags: sql, unpivot

I have just started using unpivot statement and have it working in the following context. However I want to include several where clauses on the columns I am unpivoting. Can any explain why the column names are invalid when clearly they are in the table being processed.

---working example---

```
Select [ABC1_01],value
from [dbo].[DATA1]

unpivot
( value for cols in (
    [QWE_01]
      ,[QWE_02]
      ,[ QWE_02]
  ) )u
where [ABC_01] like ‘KTC01%'
```

----end----

---Does not work----

```
select [QWE_01],value
from [dbo].[DATA1]

unpivot
( value for cols in (
 [QWE_01]
      ,[QWE_02]
      ,[QWE_03]
      ,[QWE_04]
      ,[QWE_05]
      ,[QWE_06]
      ,[QWE_07]
      ,[QWE_08]
      ,[QWE_09]
      ,[QWE_10]
      ,[QWE_11]
      ,[QWE_12]
      ,[QWE_13]
      ,[QWE_14]
      ,[QWE_15]
      ,[QWE_16]
      ,[QWE_17]
      ,[QWE_18]
      ,[QWE_19]
      ,[QWE_20]) )u
where
(
  [QWE_01] like 'ABC123%' or
      [QWE_02] like 'ABC123%' or
      [QWE_03] like 'ABC123')
```

---

I am not sure why it would not like the columns used, as this is only 1 table and not joining any.

Help appreciated

Cheers